# How to create continuous top to bottom columns in CSS without using CSS columns or column-count properties

Tags: css, wkhtmltopdf

I need to avoid CSS `columns`, `column-count` and `grid-template-rows: masonry` because the page has the option to be rendered to a PDF which doesn't support those properties.

The output should be like this:

[image]

This is what I have tried so far:

```
.container{
max-height: 200px;
}
.item{
width: 50%;
float: left;
}

<div class="container">
<div class="item">1</div>
<div class="item">2</div>
<div class="item">3</div>
<div class="item">4</div>
<div class="item">5</div>
<div class="item">6</div>
<div class="item">7</div>
<div class="item">8</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Please show your code, or at least a basic attempt, so we can offer suggestions or improvements.

Comment: What "PDF renderer" are you targetting. Does it support CSS flex or grid?

Comment: @myf wkhtmltopdf

Comment: its been very difficult to ask in stackoverflow nowadays. Always got a lot of downvotes and they just closed the questions.

Comment: I know, mods are really trigger happy and very prompt recently. But in this case, the linked question has the answer, dug inside and handwavingly filled under "column wrap" section, but it quite makes sense. The question now is: did it help you? Does wkhtmltopdf handle it well?

Comment: @myf, Ive already seen that and It is not supported by wkhtmltopdf, I only post question if I didnt find any solution in the web.

Comment: That's a pity that those information were not more prominent in the question from the start. You know, providing as much details as possible, including prior research, what was tried before and what did not work and concrete target environment is generally considered best practice when asking questions here.  Maybe if we make clear the question is about wkhtmltopdf  (add concrete version and invoking pipeline) rendering specific column layout flow (add/verify design/schema picture) of specific HTML structure, we can manage to get it reopened.

Comment: @myf, thats why theres a comment section here, people can ask what they dont understand in the question and the author can update the question and add more description. But closing the post/question is just not helpful. Also, like many of the users here, English is not our first language.

Answer (score -2):

Edit: for context, this answer was provided for [v2 of the question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/77067896/2) that asked for "output like this":

```
1 4 7
2 5 8
3 6
```

It was not clear at that time that target rendering engine is that of the wkhtmltopdf.

---

Use wrapping flex instead of floats. You can set `flex-direction: column; flex-wrap: wrap;` to the container of fixed height matching multiples of item height:

```css
.container {
  --item-height: 2em;
  height: calc(3 * var(--item-height));
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  outline: #0FF solid;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.item {
  height: var(--item-height);
  outline: #F0F solid;
  outline-offset: -2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
  <div class="item">6</div>
  <div class="item">7</div>
  <div class="item">8</div>
</div>
```